# Bootstrap DataTables - Changing Arrows

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatables

Where can I change the default "arrow" in Bootstrap's dataTables .js file? I need to have the current arrows (← and →) change to the double arrow (« and »). I've been up and down the dataTables.js file and I can't find it anywhere. I am beginning to blame it on my crossed eyes by now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the guide on http://datatables.net/blog/Twitter_Bootstrap_2 - you should just look at line 46 and 47 in the js file (http://datatables.net/media/blog/bootstrap_2/DT_bootstrap.js)

```
$(nPaging).addClass('pagination').append(
            '<ul>'+
                '<li class="prev disabled"><a href="#">&larr; '+oLang.sPrevious+'</a></li>'+
                '<li class="next disabled"><a href="#">'+oLang.sNext+' &rarr; </a></li>'+
            '</ul>'
        );
```

Comment: Thanks for answering - found the bugger hiding in a script.js file (probably a rename from the original bootstrap/datatables files).

Answer (score 0):

Found it - thanks to good old "search everywhere" function.

It is found bootstrap's script.js file (found mine on line 44).